# How to reset the GUI - without using the menu...?

Tags: interface

[image]Picture says all... The GUI is extremely small - how can I reset it??

[image]

Comment: start by trying CTRL+Mouse wheel to zoom, make sure your mouse cursor is over the part of the GUI that is too small. Otherwise, File/Defaults/Load Factory Settings.

Comment: Thank you rob. That's the first thing I did. And it worked with the new Icons, at least a little bit. But the File-Menu refuses to scale... Is there a startup-file that I can delete or change? (I can't reach file/defaults... because the menu is unreadable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1 (recommended)**

Open the directory where Blender is installed and type `cmd` in the address bar and press enter. Then run the following command to start Blender and set the *Resolution Scale* to its default value.

```
.\blender.exe --python-expr "import bpy; bpy.context.preferences.view.ui_scale = 1.0"
```

If auto-saving for the preferences is disabled, you need to manually save them.

1. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).
2. Click on the hamburger icon in the lower left corner.
3. Select *Save Preferences*.

---

**Approach 2**

This will completely reset Blender to its factory default settings.

Open the directory where Blender is installed and type `cmd` in the address bar and press enter. Then run the following command to start Blender with the factory settings.

```
.\blender.exe --factory-startup
```

Next you need to manually save the settings.

1. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).
2. Click on the hamburger icon in the lower left corner.
3. Select *Save Preferences*.

Comment: Yay! Thank you, thank you, thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @cst You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem using the checkmark next to it.